# SAP UI5 Gantt Chart color based on condition

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, gantt-chart

How can I set the fill color of a Gantt chart shape based on the value of a property in the bound json model?

Here's the code I am using to configure the sap.gantt.config.Shape :-

```js
var oRectangle = new sap.gantt.config.Shape({
    key: "Rectangle",
    shapeDataName: "schedule",
    shapeClassName: "sap.gantt.shape.Rectangle",
    shapeProperties: {
        time: "{startTime}",
        endTime: "{endTime}",
        height: 32,
        fill: "green",
        title: "{name}",
        level: 0
    }
});
```

The use case I am trying to address is :-

If there are 4 or more schedules, then fill the shape with GREEN else fill YELLOW.

I have already tried expression binding like :

```js
fill: "{= ${data>/schedule}.length > 4 ? 'green' : 'yellow' }"
```

But that didn't give any result and filled the shape with the default BLACK color.

Is there some other way of getting it possible?

Also, is there a way we can configure Gantt shapes in XML views itself ratherer than doing all these configurations the in controller?

Answer (score 0):

delete the  attribute from your shape definition.
Before you define the oRectangle, put the following code segment:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/gantt/shape/Rectangle"], function (Rectangle) {
        var shapeRectangle = Rectangle.extend("sap.test.shapeRectangle");
            shapeRectangle.prototype.getFill = function (oRawData) {
                return oRawData.color;
        };

    return shapeRectangle;
}, true);
```

After that, you have to provide the property color to the order in your data model on the same level as startTime, endTime, etc...